# "ne signifie pas que" vs "ne signifie pas pour autant que" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Is there a difference in emphasis, or tone, or implication, etc, between these two phrasings?

> Cela ne signifie pas que je suis heureux.
>
> Cela ne signifie pas pour autant que je suis heureux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pour autant "ajoute que, bien qu'on ait de nombreuses raisons (autant), ça ne suffit pas.
Exemple :
Je suis riche, cela ne signifie pas que je suis heureux.
Je suis riche et marié à une jolie femme, cela ne signifie pas pour autant que je suis heureux.

Answer (score 2):

"Cela ne signifie pas que je suis heureux" : je n'ai aucune raison d'être heureux.

"Cela ne signifie pas pour autant que je suis heureux" : j'ai des raisons d'être heureux, mais je ne le suis pas.

Comment: Bienvenue sur stack exchange !